# intermittent sending email java

Tags: java, email

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");//As discussed but does not work if the leave
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");



    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("mail@domi.cl","paswwd");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@domi.cl"));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("mail@domi.cl"));
        message.setSubject("Resumen envio masivo");
        message.setText(mensajeMail);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Below is the StackTrace:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: have you tried using my code?

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that you are unable to connect to port 587 on server smtp.office365.com. Verify this using telnet:

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 587
```

Possible reasons for this to do not work from your location are:

**Misconfigured proxy settings in Java**

If it does not work and you are in a company network, then it's most likely the firewall which causes the problem. Also check if password and email is correct.

Maybe also it works with TLS. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the SMTP port number for your domain or try my code.

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;
public class Mail {
    String senderID;
    String senderPassword;
    String hostName;
    int portNumber;
    String attachmentPath;
    String subject;
    String body;
    String cc;
    String bcc;

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getBcc() {
        return bcc;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setBcc(String bcc) {
        this.bcc = bcc;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getCc() {
        return cc;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setCc(String cc) {
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#

    public String getSenderID() {
        return senderID;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setSenderID(String senderID) {
        this.senderID = senderID;
    }

    public String getSenderPassword() {
        return senderPassword;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setSenderPassword(String senderPassword) {
        this.senderPassword = senderPassword;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public int getPortNumber() {
        return portNumber;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setPortNumber(int portNumber) {
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public String getAttachmentPath() {
        return attachmentPath;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void setAttachmentPath(String attachmentPath) {
        this.attachmentPath = attachmentPath;
    }

    // #=============================================================================================#


    // #=============================================================================================#
    public void sendMail(String receiverId) {

        try {
            // this below commented line for the HTML body text
            // MultiPartEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
            // OR
            // HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

            MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
            // setting the port number
            email.setSmtpPort(getPortNumber());
            // authenticating the user
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(getSenderID(),
                    getSenderPassword()));
            // email.setDebug(true);
            email.setSSL(true);
            // setting the host name
            email.setHostName(getHostName());
            // setting the rciever id

            email.addTo(receiverId);

            // check for user enterd cc or not
            if (getCc() != null) {
                // add the cc
                email.addCc(getCc());
            }
            // check for user enterd bcc or not
            if (getBcc() != null) {
                // add the bcc
                email.addBcc(getBcc());
            }
            // setting the sender id
            email.setFrom(getSenderID());
            // setting the subject of mail
            email.setSubject(getSubject());
            // setting message body
            email.setMsg(getBody());
            // email.setHtmlMsg("<h1>"+getBody()+"</h1>");

            // checking for attachment attachment
            if (getAttachmentPath() != null) {
                // add the attachment
                EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
                attachment.setPath(getAttachmentPath());
                attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
                email.attach(attachment);
            }

            // send the email
            email.send();
            // System.out.println("Mail sent!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
            // e.printStackTrace();
            // gl.writeWarning("Error occured in SendMail.java of sendMailWithAttachment() ");
            // gl.writeError(e);
        }
    }// sendmail()
```